# Characterization of the closure of a subspace of a dual space by bounded nets

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $E$ be a subspace of the dual $X^*$. Suppose that $y$ belongs to the weak* closure of $E$.

Does there exists a (norm) *bounded* net $(y_i)$ which converges to $y$ for the weak* topology ?

I think that it is related to the Krein-Smulian theorem but it is not clear for me.

If we can choose a sequence instead of a net, it is immediate (a bounded weak* convergent sequence is bounded) but I does not believe that it is possible.

Comment: If you have a sequence that does the job, then you're done. Sequences are nets.